# A default and easy way to display a spinner while performing lengthy operations

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm transferring huge chunks of data while my users work with their forms. Besides trying to optimize the code to ensure for the fastest connections, I'd like to display a spinning image in the middle of the form to notify the user that the software is sweating it's parts of to get the info as quickly as possible.

I'd like to point to following considerations.

- Can I use an arbitrary animated image (e.g. abc.gif)?
- Is it possible (suggested, even) to use the default spinner seen in the CRM?
- Can such a solution be applicable even for older versions of CRM?
- IS is possible (recommended, maybe) to use jQuery and it's cool effects?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes you can use any animated gif.  Add as a web resource in CRM 2011.
2. You can take the default spinner and add as a web resource.  I'd strongly recommend you don't try and address it directly.
3. Yes but the way you manage your scripts is less prescribed. No solutions or web resources to use in CRM4.
4. Absolutely.  See below.

The jQuery plugin [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#download) is one of the most popular for potentially long running OData calls from which you need to prevent further UI interaction.

Since you'll need to attach directly to a DOM element it's use won't be supported.  However, as long as you stick with attaching to the `<body>` element and avoid digging too far down into the DOM like for example onto the markup for specific form sections you'll be OK.

For CRM 2011 we use our own Web Resource to wrap BlockUI providing a very simple API enforcing consistent binding to the `<body>` element which also checks for the inclusion of jQuery and BlockUI scripts (Web Resources) on the form.

Same deal applies for CRM 4 but script management is much more down to how your team are currently managing customisations and dependencies.

The easier you can make it to use, the less likely other developers on the team are to go off and try and roll their own causing horrible inconsistencies in the final UX.

Comment: I'm still new to CRM so, please, stay patient. 1. Where do I get default spinner? You mean those green rotators, right? 2. I'm working with an IFRAME so in there I can play around with my spinner but I'm unsure how. Do you mean just to display an IMG tag with *z-index* properly set? How do I tell it to appear/disappear? 3. Is it too much to hope for if i wish for a default functionality built-in into CRM? Maybe in Polaris (2013)?